# How can I have conditional formatting with lower priority than manual formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

I know how to do the formatting that I want. The document should have conditional formatting. However When I added it. It covered the manual formatting.

It there a way to say do this conditional formatting, unless I say otherwise with some manual formatting?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** Create an extra column called ManualFormat and fill it with checkboxes.

**Step 2** Add to your conditional formatting a condition that the checkbox must be false

*Not the most elegant solution but you can't easily see if something is already formatted from the conditional format feature.*

Comment: A good idea, but it will not work for me, as I would have to train my collaborators to tick the box. +1 but no tick.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Why is someone highlighting data? Often I find the reason why people are highlighting something is because they do not have a checkbox to indicate something, perhaps their manual formatting itself could be a checkbox. So if they are simply highlighting an entire row yellow then you can make a checkbox column called highlight entire row. Maybe you should post example data of how you are highlighting and why they are highlighting in conflict of your formatting.

Comment: Same reason they make heading by changing font size. It is not the right time to educate them.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor can you put in your question or here a small sample of your conflicting conditional formatting.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I want to play with a small sample of what you are experiencing so I can try out a few different solutions.

Comment: It is arranged that date progresses left to right. Some cells are highlighted for some reason, but only if there is data in them. I want to add auto-format, to make it clear if a row has data. To do this I have created a conditional-format, that highlights non-empty cells and all cells to the left of non-empty cells (to create a bar graph look).